# Homemade concrete blocks for fire pit and starfire direct DYI propane fire pit

Tags: fire-pit

Im Buying concrete molds for a DYI landscaping projects. I want to use some of the same bricks for a DYI starfire direct propane fire pit in the back yard. Ive heard this can be dangerous? Would this still be true with the propane burner at the top of the pit?

Comment: Depending just how DIY you are, either buy castable refractory for those blocks or look up "homemade castable refractory" for making them. ...or "fire clay"

Comment: it is not really dangerous, it tends to crumble.

Comment: One method is to use a fine sawdust in the mix after the blocks are dry they can be burned out this method smokes like crazy but is how I built a much larger metal casting forge on the cheep.